# How to implement single sign on (SSO) with identity server 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I have one MVC application which used identity server 3 authetication.Now I have second MVC application.I want when user login into the first application that user should get log in the second application too.For this, I want to implement SSO in identity server3.Can anyone help me for how to achieve SSO with identity server3?

Answer (score 0):

If both Clients are correctly registered in the Idsrv3's configuration, you should have Single Sign On automatically.